# mat-select: Programmatically pre-selecting items

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-material-7

I am trying to figure out how to display a mat-select in a dialog and have some of the mat-options preselected. I've created a simple example to demonstrate what I want to do:

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-angular-select-defaults-example?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

In my example, I want to display a selectable list of colors, with a few of the colors preselected. I first create a mat-select and its contents (mat-options) by iterating over an array of strings in my dialog's TS file:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Colors" formControlName="selectedColors" multiple>
   <mat-option *ngFor="let color of allColors" value="{{color}}">{{color}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

This works just fine. In my dialog's TS file, I have the following arrays declared:

```
this.allColors =  ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];
this.defaultSelections = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
```

Note the 2nd array, "defaultSelections": I want to have these items pre-selected when the dialog is displayed. I can't seem to find / figure out how to do this.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: just, when create the form use this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ selectedColors: [this.defaultSelections] });. Mat-select with multiple expect an array with the values of the selections. Yes! a FormControl can be store an array, an object, a string...

Comment: Yes as like Eliseo said, you are alright just need to put the word  inside the [] like ```selectedColors: [this.defaultSelections]``` instead of ```selectedColors: []``` .. Working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-w7eclt

Comment: I figured it was something as simple as that, but I was obviously looking in the wrong place. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `ReactiveForms` you can use the default value property on `FormControl` to set the initial values of `mat-select`.

```
this.defaultSelections = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  selectedColors: [this.defaultSelections]
});
```

A working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-angular-select-defaults-example-qeegsa).

Comment: How can I use this in array containing objects in which each object have id? Do I store object in the formbuilder array or just the object ids?